# How to configure an Internet mail server to use with IIS website

Tags: email, iis, smtp, webserver, exchange-server

I am looking for a little direction to my problem. Short story, I have a website hosted on a web server. I pay a yearly subscription. This year I am planning on taking it off and hosting it internally. I already backed up, restored, and installed all necessary components (on Windows BTW with IIS, PHP, and MySQL). The site works great internal and by IP address externally through a firewall. (IP address for now until my web host subscription expires, then I will forward and register DNS).

But now this is my problem, my website has email functionality which works on my providers server. I want to install a local mail server for my website that will wind up sending and receiving emails through my website. I am lost here. No sure which path I should take. I have installed and used Exchange 2003 in the past just for internal domains, nothing for internet AND internet.

Anyone with ideas, links, suggestions? I see that IIS does support SMTP virtual servers, is this a possible route? If so, what about POP3 or IMAP (incoming) server solutions?

Thanks

Edit
---Update On Situation---
So far I have configured a local exchange server that works with my local webserver. I then created a CNAME in my web host DNS zone for my IP address. I created a simple subdomain for my site redirected to my home web server. Everything works great, internal email through Exchange 2003 from website on IIS, redirected DNS names, almost there. Now I just need to create Internet Mail functionality in Exchange. Went through the Exchanges wizard to "open system" for Internet mail, created new SMTP connector and ....nothing for external mail test. Failed! Thought everything was configured properly. I also tried to open all ports on firewall, 25 and 110.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to Exchange Internet mail SMTP connector configuration:
[Configure Exchange Internet Mail SMTP Connector](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319426)

Well, I did figure it out. I was on the right path and everything was working but I just configured my client wrong and my ISp blocked port 25, duh. CHanged port to unused 366. But here is a little tip for anyone that may need to figure this out in the future.

1)Setup install IIS with default SMTP and NNTP virtual servers.

2)Install Exchange into organization. Internal naming convention doesn't really make a difference between internal to externally if you are behind a firewall. Basically this means you don't have to create a seperate zone in DNS if using this for a seperate domain hosted elsewhere. Hope this didn't confuse anyone.

3)Right click on server name in Exchange System Manager and go to Internet Mail Wizard

4)If you want your clients to hold a different domain email address than your internal you can setup in exchange through 
Exchange System Manager >> Recipients >> Recipient Policies
Then add a Masquerade in Default SMTP Virtual Server

5)Have a gmail Internet SMTP connector set to smtp.gmail.com as smart host with a gmail email account settings and TLS checked

6)Default SMTP VS set with outbound port 587 and TLS checked

If you need to change SMTP ports too, don't forget to change not just firewall but also inside Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something like PostMarkApp to send transactional email from the website, and use hosted email (Google Apps for Domains) for your email. Its a pain to run a real mail server.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I kinda like the abuse and this will kinda be an educational task for myself. I like punishment. I looked into it and what you said is exactly what I should do. I still want to test an internal mail server.